# make request and response available in scope node js

Tags: node.js

I have this `module.exports`

```
module.exports = {
  defaultStrings: function() {
    return "Hello World" +
           "Foo - Bar";
  },
  urlSlug: function(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w\s]+/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,'-');
  }
};
```

I want to be able to use `request` or `response` inside function `defaultStrings` how would I include that with a minimum change of the given code?

```
  defaultStrings: function(req, res, next) { // <--- This is not working it says Cannot call method 'someGlobalFunction' of undefined
    return "Hello World" +
           "Foo - Bar" + req.someGlobalFunction();
  },
```

In my `app.js` I require the file in

```
strings = require('./lib/strings'),
```

And this is how it is being called inside `app.js`

```
app.get('/',
        middleware.setSomeOperation,
        routes.index(strings);
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  How are you calling `defaultStrings` from your outside code?

Comment: Have you extended the req object with someGlobalFunction or are you attempting to call a function that exists in the global scope?

Comment: @Joe I'm sorry I forgot to mention that. This file is being include in other file using `    `filename = require('./lib/filename')`

Comment: @pdoherty926 this `someGlobalFunction` can be used anywhere the `req` is available and I even tested somewhere else and it works.

Comment: Can you post the code that is referencing defaultStrings (not importing) - perhaps in an app.use(...) statement?

Comment: I just updated my question with more info.

Comment: And how is routes.index using it?

Comment: @dc5 inside route/index.js I just simply call `content = strings.defaultStrings();`

Comment: There's the problem - you need to pass req, resp to it

Comment: @dc5 I just figured that :D. you can post an answer to this if you wish and I will accept that :)

Comment: @gr3co was on the same track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When are you calling `defaultStrings`? If you are calling it directly from your `routes` i.e. by using `app.get("some_url", defaultStrings)`, then `req` and `res` should be available to you.

EDIT: It appears that you were calling it by: `content = strings.defaultStrings();` inside of your `index` function. In order to pass on the `req` and `res` arguments you must simply change your call to `content = strings.defaultStrings(req,res,cb)`, where `cb` is the callback defined by `index`.

Comment: The problem is not about calling `defaultStrings` but having to call `someGlobalFunction` which is undefined when calling that inside the `defaultStrings` function

Comment: @Ali yes, but it is throwing an error because `req` is not defined when `defaultStrings` is called. If your function is called as a callback of `app.get()` then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It's not someGlobalFunction that is undefined, it's req.

Comment: Updated my question with more info.

Comment: @Ali so.... `defaultStrings` is the callback for your `index` function? If so, in your `index` function you should just call `callback(req,res)` instead of just `callback()`

Comment: @gr3co I'm so sorry! that was a mistake I just updated that one again.

Comment: what does your `index` look like?

Comment: If you can check the comment above on my question and update your answer accordingly would be so much appreciated since that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using node.js with express.

If you want access to the http request and response you've got a few options:

**Add function myMiddleware as a middleware for all routes**

```
var myMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route); // Just print the request route
  next(); // Needed to invoke the next handler in the chain
}

app.use(myMiddleware); //This will add myMiddleware to the chain of middlewares
```

**Add function myMiddleware as a middleware for a specific route**

```
var myMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route); // Just print the request route
  next(); // Needed to invoke the next handler in the chain
}

app.get('/', myMiddleware, function(...) {}); //This will add myMiddleware to '/'
```

**Add function myHandler as a route handler**

```
var myHandler = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.route); // Just print the request route
  send(200); // As the last step of the chain, send a response
}

app.get('/', myHandler); //This will bind myHandler to '/'
```